# Clojure : Idiomatic (when (predicate x) x)

Tags: clojure

In the same way you can convert

```
(if (something)
    something
    fallback)
```

into the shorter version :

```
(or something fallback)
```

I was wondering if there is a composition function/elegant builtin for threading a value into the validation of a predicate like :

```
(when (pred x)
  x)
```

Into something like

```
(thread-pred pred x)
```

I could easily build some function or macro to do it, but I'd rather not go NIH here.

Comment: Nope. Nothing out of the box. I'd recommend to stick with `(when (pred x) x)` approach. It's idiomatic enough.

Comment: A closer analogy is `(and (pred x) x)`, which returns `false` instead of `nil`.

Comment: @Thumbnail It returns `(pred x)` rather than `nil`. That may be `false` or `nil`, depending on how `pred` behaves.

Comment: @amalloy Oops! Of course it does.

Comment: For the sake of completeness I also thought of (cond-> x predicate identity), but it's quite less readable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It took me way longer than I care to admit - but here you go:

Beware this might explode.

```
(defmacro -pred-> 
  [pred body] 
  `(when (~pred ~body) ~body))

(macroexpand-1 '(-pred-> odd? 3))
=> (clojure.core/when (odd? 3) 3)

(-pred-> odd? 3)
=> 3

(-pred-> odd? 2)
=> nil
```

---

EDIT: as the comments correctly pointed out it would be wiser to let-bind the body to an autogensym like so:

```
(defmacro -pred-> 
  [pred body] 
  `(let [b# ~body] 
     (when (~pred b#) b#)))
```

Comment: Watch out, you (potentially) double eval body!

Comment: Should just be a function. You're using no macro features.

Comment: I mark it as accepted, though the comment from OlegTheCat "Nope. Nothing out of the box." is the straight answer. Still useful anyway, I learned a bit of macro syntax. Thx